# Update em um campo que não pode ficar com valor negativo

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Preciso fazer um *update* em um determinado campo, onde o mesmo deve chegar no mínimo até "zero" não pode ficar negativo. E quando chegar a zero preciso que ele de o *update* da quantidade restante no próximo campo. "O ajuste esta para ele dar a baixa na quantidade primeiro no registro com a menor expira "FIFO".

Exemplo: Vou dar baixa de 9948

```
Unit Quantity      Expira
    9947         10/10/2017
    9947         10/11/2017
```

Forma errada :

```
Unit Quantity      Expira
    -1           10/10/2017
    9947         10/11/2017
```

Forma correta :

```
Unit Quantity      Expira
     0           10/10/2017
    9946         10/11/2017
```

Query :

```
UPDATE invdtl
   SET untqty = untqty - 9948
 WHERE prtnum = 'OP-CX44LT'
   AND invsts = 'LIB'
   AND lst_arecod IN ('1SUPRCK')
   AND expire_dte <= TRUNC(expire_dte)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia utilizar uma função analítica para identificar os registros que precisarão ser atualizados, a função `greatest` para não permitir que determinado valor fique negativo, e o comando `merge` ( ou um loop simples ) para atualizar a coluna.

Algo como:

```
merge into invdtl a
using (
  select a.*
       , greatest( untqty - :quantidade_a_baixar, 0 ) nova_quantidade
  from (
    select rowid rid
         , untqty
         , sum( untqty ) over( order by to_number( expire_dte ) ) - untqty qtd_acumulada
    from   invdtl
    where  prtnum      = 'OP-CX44LT'
    and    invsts      = 'LIB'
    and    lst_arecod in ('1SUPRCK')
    and    expire_dte <= trunc(expire_dte)
  ) a
  where  acumulado < :quantidade_a_baixar
) b on ( a.rowid = b.rid )
when matched then
  update set a.untqty = b.nova_quantidade
```

Answer (score 0):

É assim que está mesmo campo mas em registro diferente

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você deve editar a sua pergunta e colocar essa imagem lá e excluir essa 'resposta'.

Answer (score 0):

Em tese (só testando) uma trigger de update na tabela poderia resolver :

Algo do tipo

```
CREATE TRIGGER BEFORE UPDATE IN TABELA ...

IF :NEW.VALOR < 0 THEN
   :NEW.VALOR := 0;
   INSERT INTO TABELA (...,VALOR,...) VALUES (.....ABS(:NEW-VALOR),....);
END IF;
```

se o valor ficar negativo se "zera" o mesmo e se lança ele positivo em outro registro.